# Android service doesn't send notifications on app exit

Tags: android, service, notifications, exit

I have created a **background service** that checks for value changes in my **Firebase Database** and sends a `Notification` if there are any changes. The service notifies for value changes as long as the app is running. When I close the app, I stop receiving notifications.  My `onStartCommand` contains a new thread comprising of a firebase value event listener. As the value changes

I call `sendNotification` method. Here's my complete service class:

public class NotifyService extends Service
{

```
Firebase mRef;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mRef= new Firebase(myURL);
    Runnable run = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            mRef.child("politics").child("story1").child("title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                        String data = (String)p1.getValue();
                        sendNotification(data);
                    } 

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                    }
                });

            mRef.child("sports").child("story1").child("title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                        String data = (String)p1.getValue();
                        sendNotification(data);
                    } 

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                    }
                });

            mRef.child("science").child("story1").child("title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                        String data = (String)p1.getValue();
                        sendNotification(data);
                    } 

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                    }
                });

            mRef.child("gossip").child("story1").child("title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                        String data = (String)p1.getValue();
                        sendNotification(data);
                    } 

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                    }
                });
        }};
    Thread serviceThread = new Thread(run);
    serviceThread.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "activity destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void sendNotification(String title){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotifyService.this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nicon); 
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nlicon));
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Story")   
    .setContentText(title);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(NotifyService.this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( 
        0,           
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT      
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

I call it with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
startService(i);
```

What is it that doesn't let the notifications appear after app exit. I suspect it is something wrong with the notification method.

Comment: Provide the code of your service class and how you start your service.

Comment: Better remove the thread and paste the code in onStartCommand method. I think the problem is with asynchronous execution of thread

Comment: @Krishna tried without new thread but doesn't solve the problem. I even tried it with just a notification inside onStartCommand that displays after 20s. If I keep the app open it displays but if I exit the app it doesn't display the notification.

Comment: By "exit the app", you mean you back all the way out to the home screen?  Do the notifications also stop if you put the app in the background by pressing the Home button?

Comment: @qbix notifications stop when I completely exit/finish/destroy my app, putting it in background works good and shows notifications.

Comment: From what you have described, something is causing the service to stop, which is puzzling given that the service is sticky.  When you put the app in the back ground and then kill it by swiping it from the task list, the service should restart automatically after a few seconds.  Do you see the toast showing the service restarted and notifications for that case?  When you "exit" your app backing out of an activity, the service should continue running, but you say the notifications stop, right?  You don't call `stopService()` in your code anywhere do you?

Comment: any luck? as @qbix  said, check if you have called stopService() anywhere in your code. There can be an issue of memory with your testing device. check it. Once it get solved, post the solution here.

Comment: No luck yet. I never called stopService() in my project. I read that it was a bug in android 4.4.2 that kills services on killing apps however I can see my service running in settings. I have tried a whole day and thus dropped this idea for now.

Comment: Hi have you found any solution regarding this? I'm having the same problem. :(

Comment: @Kairi San I haven't worked on it since then but I think we should work for some solution as it might help others. Do you see your service running in Settings > Apps?

Comment: Not yet, i'll check it :) yes we should.

Comment: @HasaanAhmed have you tried using this in your manifest `<receiver android:name="com.mmi.mwos.activities.NotificationPublisher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Answer (score 1):

My service was apparently running in settings, but it was actually getting killed after the app was killed.

To keep your service running, instead of

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

use this:

```
Intent serviceintent =new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent =PendingIntent.getService(this,0, serviceintent,0);
    AlarmManager alarm =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pendingintent);  
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),5000, pendingintent);
```

This ensures your service keeps using `AlarmManager` every 5 seconds, so no matter what happens, the service will keep running.